# Refresh MySQL table after updation

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have three tables A, B, C. I have a entity D which is a resultant of these three tables obtained using inner joins on various attributes. Now, I got a row updated in table A and a new row got added in table B. How can this be managed, so that my table D gets updated automatically? Each of these tables consists of 100 000 records.

Comment: for that you use on insert and on update triggers.. But your question is to vage

Comment: Why not create D as a View rather than a Table - then this wouldn’t be an issue?

Comment: As you describe D it sounds more like a query than an entity. Maybe you should not have a table for it?